# Bootmenu not loading

Tags: boot

I changed my laptop partition a little now it can't load the boot menu and showing error message every time i start my laptop. How do I fix this problem or rescue my data as I can access them with ubuntu live USB.

Comment: And what does the error say...?

Answer (score 0):

you must re install grub, the easiest way is to log in with a `live usb disk of ubuntu` , then mount your ubuntu partition lets say it is mounted at /media/ubuntu, then go to terminal and do:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/ubuntu sda
```

hope my syntax is correct ;)